# Why do Predators prefer to hunt during heatwaves?

Tags: predator-series, predator

In the first *Predator* movie, it's mentioned that the Predator only comes to Earth to hunt during the hottest years.

> ANNA GONSALVES: When I was little, we found a man. He looked like... like butchered. The old women in the village crossed themselves and whispered crazy things, said strange things, "El diablo, cazador de hombres." **Only in the hottest years this happens. And this year it grows hot.** We begin finding our men. We found them sometimes without their skin, and sometimes much, much worst. "El que hace trofeos de los hombres" means "the demon who makes trophies of man".
>
> <sub>*Predator* (1987)</sub>

The same is implied in *Predator 2*, since the events of the movie take place during a heatwave.

Why would a Predator prefer to hunt in hot weather? Wouldn't high temperatures hinder their thermal vision, rather than help it? Is this ever explained in any related works?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It was suggested in the [*Alien vs. Predator* novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(novel)) by Marc Cerasini that Yautja are a cold-blooded species, like reptiles on Earth, and therefore require a warm environment to function optimally.

> **Lex noted that Scar wore a kind of mesh underwear under his plated armor and that the Predator was careful to discard as little of that material as possible,** though Scar did detach a damaged bit of it, discarding it within Lex's reach. When he was otherwise occupied, Lex casually lifted the mesh and fingered it. It was made of some kind of flexible metal and was quite hot to the touch. Even more peculiar was the fact that the material remained hot long after it was separated from its power source and, presumably, from Scar's body heat -- if indeed he had any. **All this led Lex to the conclusion that the mesh was some sort of heating source and was probably as vital a piece of equipment to Scar as an Aqua-Lung is to a human deep-sea diver.**
>
> **If the Predator's species had evolved from some type of extraterrestrial reptile, then they were most probably ectothermic -- meaning their body temperature was regulated by external climactic conditions.**
>
> Mammals generated their own body heat, but reptiles depended on external temperatures for thermoregulation and maintaining a balanced metabolism, which was why most reptiles thrived in hot climates and eschewed places like the polar regions. In fact, weird things happened to some species of reptile if exposed to a cold environment: They became sluggish and less aggressive, and females sometimes gave birth to live young instead of laying eggs in a nest and hatching them externally.
>
> Reptiles could also die in cold that was too intense or sustained, and **Lex noticed several patches of rough, cracked hide on Scar's hands that resembled the chilblains that appeared on humans in icy weather.** While Lex was no expert in the fields of extraterrestrial biology or herpetology, **it didn't look as if Scar was holding up well in the brutal climate of Antarctica.**
>
> <sub>*Alien vs. Predator* novelisation by Marc Cerasini</sub>